# not enough space for grub2 to install core.img - how to install Scientific Linux?

Tags: linux, installation, grub2

I have Windows 10 -- and I've already shrunk its partitions.  There's plenty of disk space (two disks, 1900G on one and 214G on the other available).  I'm trying to use Scientific Linux's installer, but it persists in saying that

> sda may not have enough space for grub2 to embed core.img when using the xfs file system on the partition.

How do I get Scientific Linux to install?  I've seen some notes talking about `grub-install --force /dev/sda1` but I see no command line interface for that.

Should I give up on Scientific Linux and try Centos, or Fedora, or (sigh, if I absolutely have to) Ubuntu?  (note: I've already shrunk the Windows ntfs partitions).

Comment: Seeing that the "Scientific Linux Everything" is only about 8.4GB (from their website) - and if I'm reading your writing is correct that you prepared 214GB free space for it to work on - it should install without issue. Can you clarify if you really have the right amount of free space? And sure if sda is the correct HDD?

Comment: Yes, there is plenty of space.  Problem appears to be that there apparently are constraints on where core.img can go -- and that causes the insufficient space.  Something to do with the master boot record.  The "--force" option attempts to bypass the issue by putting core.img in a possibly unsafe but roomy place; unfortunately, the installer has no command line that I'm aware of to use such a feature.

Comment: Additionally, I'll add that I am able to successfully install Scientific Linux so long as I do so without the boot loader.  Of course, when I reboot, I get a message "No operating system".

Answer (score 1):

Core.img is placed between mbr and first disk partition. Hence some sufficient space should be left. Please check below link. I faced this problem and issue was solved with below solution.

```
part-init /dev/sda mbr
part-add  /dev/sda primary 63 2048000
```

Observe that between mbr and sda1 i have left some sectors. sda1 starts from sector 63

[link](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?274701-GRUB2-core-img-not-fitting-between-MBR-and-sector-63)

Comment: Thank you for this -- but I don't know where the part-init and part-add commands are; just did a search for them along my path and they're not present (using which).  Also, I gave up and formatted the disk for linux only (SL 7.5) and no longer have a windows setup to try this out.

Comment: If UEFI and drive is gpt partitioned then you have to have a 1MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag. Grub does not want to install to a tiny MBR without either the space after the MBR with MBR partitioning or space with gpt and bios_grub.  Post this in question. `sudo parted -l`